Configuring SQL Server database connection string with Angular app
I am trying to practice my full stack skills by bringing back to life a big project I worked on with 10+ people by myself. I remember at some point I learned that there is appsettings.json and appsetings.Development.json and that you put the connection string there.
The catch that always confused me is that we are supposed to .gitignore the file so that it doesn't get exposed right? That makes sense but it also means that I don't have those two files from when this app was alive and that I need to remake them in some way. I am sure I have the database up and connected to an azure server, as I was able to make a SQL query to a database that I filled with some dummy information this morning.
PS C:\Users\my-name> sqlcmd -S appName.database.windows.net,1433 -d appName -U 'SA' -P 'PW'
1> SELECT * FROM companions
2>
3> GO
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server cosminis, Line 1
Invalid object name 'companions'.
1> SELECT * FROM Cosminis.companions
2> Go
companionId user_fk     species_fk  emotion     nickname                       hunger      mood        timeSinceLastChangedMood timeSinceLastChangedHunger timeSinceLastPet        companion_birthday      TimeSinceLastFed
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------------ -------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
          6           3           1           5 Supernovog!                             50           7  2024-08-02 19:51:38.600    2024-08-02 19:51:38.600 2024-08-02 19:51:38.600 2024-08-02 19:51:38.600 2024-08-02 19:51:38.600
          7           1           4           5 Seth                                    69           6  2024-08-02 19:52:11.037    2024-08-02 19:52:11.037 2024-08-02 19:52:11.037 2024-08-02 19:52:11.037 2024-08-02 19:52:11.037
          9           5           6           5 Asmodeus                                 6           2  2024-08-02 19:52:22.417    2024-08-02 19:52:22.417 2024-08-02 19:52:22.417 2024-08-02 19:52:22.417 2024-08-02 19:52:22.417
         10           4           3           5 Test                                   100           8  2024-08-02 19:52:23.693    2024-08-02 19:52:23.693 2024-08-02 19:52:23.693 2024-08-02 19:52:23.693 2024-08-02 19:52:23.693

(4 rows affected)

So I know that the database

has information,
is connected to my server/API in some way.

Using the following line I can connect to my application through swagger but it only works locally and not on my website because I have the file .gitignored. I don't understand how to separate this from a user environment.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CosminisOfficialDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));

Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong in my configuration?
I was thinking this could be appsettings.Development.json
{
  "Authentication": {
    "ClientId": "Client",
    "ClientSecret": "Secret",
    "AllowedHosts": [
      "localhost",
      "localhost:5000",
      "localhost:5001"
    ],
    "Attempts": 3,
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "CS": "Server=tcp:DB.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=Active Directory Default;"
    }
  }
}

and then using this for the regular appsettings.json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Devstring": "Devstring;" //Using dotnet user-secrets or something?
  }
}

How can I keep my connection string secret but have my app online?
Been using AI and asking friends and using the debugger and trying to use the Swagger UI and also all the tools in the Azure portal.
Where I am calling the API
export const environment = 
{
  production: false, 
  api: 'https://cosminis-fge8geh4gjfdf4ca.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net',
  auth:
  {
    domain: "dev-lj8y5w8u.us.auth0.com",
    clientId: "Lq2lP0EYqPCAqzFtXLYdphFwobokBBw0",
    redirectUri: window.location.origin
  }
};




Add the Connection string in the Environment Variables section of the Azure App Service.

I did add the connection string to environment variables. Maybe I should use the default one on the site instead of the one I added? I will add a picture above in the post

Make sure the connectionstring which u have set is able to retrieve in the code.

You are retrieving it with different name in code.cross check once again

I updated it back to CosminiDBConnectionString in program.cs. I see that it is not listed as "true" for slot setting, and that the deploy slot setting uses AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING. Do you think that might be contributing?

No...That will be considered only in case if you are doing any swapping.Try to retrieve the value using the Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING");

or else add AddEnvironmentVariables in your Program.cs and try with the same code.


we are supposed to .gitignore the file so that it doesn't get exposed right?


Yes, .gitignore file helps to ignore the files/folders deploying to production when you are using GitHub.


How can I keep my connection string secret but have my app online?


To secure the ConnectionString, you need to set the secrets either in EnvironmentVariables/UserSecrets( in secrets.json file)/  appettings.Development.json ( which you are following).
For the Azure App Service, set them in the Environment variables section.



For the Azure App Service,instead of Key-Value pair, set the value as Key vault reference.
Refer my SOThread to store the secrets in KeyVault.

While Configuring the DB from Connected Service in VS, you can see the option to save it in the Azure Key Vault.




Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong in my configuration?


The issue is with your Azure App Setting.

The name of the Application Setting has to be same as the name which you have set in the appsettings.json/appsettings.Development.json file (and retrieve it using the same name).


builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Devstring") 


To verify the App Service Setting I am sending the value to Logs.

var app = builder.Build();

var conn = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Devstring");
var log = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
log.LogInformation($"ConnectionString from Azure App Service: {conn}");

Local Output:

App Service Output:


I got it to build and used your logging idea as well. Thank you for the advice. Unfortunately, while the app says that it is building, it also is not actually working for a swagger api still. I don't know what is going on but I am just gonna keep researching...

If possible please share your code repo.

https://github.com/CosminiInc/CosminiOfficial
